How can I get smoother Graphics() in pixi.js?
I am trying to draw using pixi.js version 8.1.5 Graphics:
const graphics = new Graphics()

graphics
  .clear()
  .moveTo(km.graphic.origin.x, km.graphic.origin.y)
  .lineTo(km.graphic.center.x, km.graphic.center.y)
  .stroke({ color: km.graphic.color, width: km.graphic.lineWidth })
  .circle(km.graphic.center.x, km.graphic.center.y, km.graphic.radius)
  .fill(km.graphic.color);

My problem is that both lines and boundary of circle are jagged:

antialias is turned on:
const app = new Application();

await app.init({
  backgroundAlpha: 0,
  resizeTo: this.element,
  antialias: true,
});

I also tried, per common internet advice, adding to init(): autodensity: true, resolution: window.devicePixelRatio and resolution: 2, with no change in result.
I cannot use graphics-smooth library, since it only supports pixi.js v7.
How can I achieve smoother lines and graphic boundaries?
